# Could not undersand racket function

Tags: racket, typed-racket

My proffesor gave us this function:

```
(: every? : (All (A) (A -> Boolean) (Listof A) -> Boolean))

(define (every? pred lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (pred (first lst))
           (every? pred (rest lst)))))
```

I couldn't understand the meaning of: `All (A) (A -> Boolean)`.
please can someone can explain to me - what is the meaning of the variable, what the function get, what is it do and what is it return because i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's give the function `every?` a spin at the repl:

```
> (every? even? (list 1 2 3 4))
#f

> (every? char? (list #\a #\b #\c))
#t
```

Note that the type of the first list `(list 1 2 3 4)` is `(Listof Number)`.
The type of the second list `(list #\a #\b #\c)` is `(Listof Char)`.

What type should the `lst` argument of `every?` have?
Clearly it needs to be a list, but what type are the elements?
We don't know, so we make it a `(Listof A)`, where `A` stands
for some (unknown) type.

However the predicate `pred` is called on the elements in the list,
so the type must match. In the first example: `even?` has the type
"function from number to boolean" aka `(A -> Boolean)`.

In general we need the type: `(A -> Boolean)` for the predicate.

This becomes:

```
  (: every? : (All (A) (A -> Boolean) (Listof A) -> Boolean))
```

Comment: But what is the meaning of `pred` is? where is this function declare?

Comment: If you write `(every? even? (list 1 2 3 4))` in your program, the funtion `every?` is called with two arguments. The first argument is the function `even?` the other is the list `(1 2 3 4)`. Since `every?` is defined as `(define (every? pred lst) ...)` the names `pred` and `lst` are used inside the body to refer to the first and second argument respectively. That is: there is no `pred` function declared. It's the name for the function passed to `every?`.

Comment: Bonus info: The name `pred` is short for predicate. A predicate is a function that returns returns a boolean value. In Scheme and Racket names of predicates normally end in a question mark.